# Format all cells in column from date to text

Tags: excel, office-2013

I have an excel document with about 500 rows.
I need to format all the cells in , let's say, B column from date to text.

This is how it looks like now:

```
2012-06-15
2012-06-01
2012-06-14
```

What it looks like when formated to text:

```
41075
41061
41074
```

It has come to my understanding that this is a timestamp representing days since 1st januari 1900, right? Anyhow, this is not what I want. I want the value of the field to be exactly what it is but with the column type of text. I've found various solutions for this using functions like this: `=TEXT(B1, "yyyy-mm-dd")` but that is not reformating the cell, it is extracting a value from one cell, reformat it and represent is as text in another.

The rule I'm after: `I want all cells in B column to have the type text without changing the value`

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to have it as text - what's the issue with the formatted value?

Comment: Can we assume the text representation you are after is used some where else in excel?

Comment: Also is this value typed in or populated from another scource / program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a situation where columns `A` to `D` are dates of 500 rows you then:

1. Use the `=TEXT(A1, "yyyy-mm-dd")` function you describe in cell `E1`.
2. Copy this formula 4 columns wide, and 500 rows down.
3. Then copy and paste **values** to the preceding cells.

**Copy Example:**

[image: Copy]

**Output:**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1):

You're right, Excel stores dates internally as number of days since January 1st, 1900 (apart from a minor leap year bug).

Thus, I'm afraid you cannot have both:

- Either you keep the value e.g. (`41075`) and simply *format* it as a date, so it'll be displayed as `2012-06-15` -
- Or you convert it to text format - but then you either

  - Lose the underlying value - if you convert it to the format you wish with a text function as you mentioned
  - Keep the value (`41075`), but cannot see the date

Comment: Thank you for the for your fast answer. The reason for all this is that I am going to import this excel document in a third party service, which have a strange way of handling dates. I've stumbled upon another "solution": Copy all the rows and paste it in a text editor like notepad, then copy it from notepad and back in excel, thus overwriting all cells. Doesn't it seem quite strange for Excel to not have an easier way to do this?

Comment: Does the import work if you use `TEXT`(...`to create the string?

Comment: Yes it does. As long as the cell is in type string(text?) it works. They are not investigating the value it self. They just check the cell type and use that.

Answer (score 1):

If you are typing in the values you can by adding a `'` before the values to keep it as text.

e.g.

[image: Example Output]

But depending on the method the third party service uses to import these values this may not work and I bet you will not get around it unless you export it to a text editor and import it again.

**Also** try to play with diferent types of text for your third party service, e.g. `"2012-06-15"` as some see the quotes and remove them.

Comment: The problem is not initially representing them as text, that I can do (Just set the cell type to text and type in the value). The problem is that I've got a 500 rows document with 4 cells containing dates in each row. I now need them to be converted without having to manually change all of them.

Comment: I would suggest that you can use the `text` function you discribe and copy this formula 4 columns wide, and 500 rows down, then copy and paste values to the precedings cells.